# How to completely rebuild boot partition with grub as well?

Tags: boot, grub, opensuse, usb-drive

openSUSE 11.4, I have boot partition on pendrive.

The problem is when I boot computer, grub immediately shows error "file not found" (I have no clue which file) and switches to "rescue mode".

I can boot computer from another pendrive, but I would like to use the original one (the one mentioned above). I tried to refresh grub using Yast, or manually by executing

```
grub --batch < /etc/grub.conf
```

or by copying all the files from working pendrive to the non-working (editing device.map after that), still no success, "rescue mode" is all I see.

I know one way to rebuild the content of the pendrive (it contains only boot partition) by reinstalling entire system again, and this will force building boot partition again correctly, but I am looking for something more clever.

So, how to rebuild entire boot partition+grub, not just polish 2 or 3 files within it.

Comment: Ok, so first - how did you create the boot partition on the pendrive in the first place? Second - would it satisfy you to just make the original pendrive work exactly as the second one does?

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz, The original pendrive was creating during installation process (second too, that's why I know for sure it is valid and working way to create boot partition+grub).

Yes, it would be completely OK with me to make the first pendrive as the second one (please note, those pendrives differs in capacity and partition sizes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so if it satisfies you to have the old pendrive work as the second one, here's how you can do it:

1. Back-up the contents of the old pendrive.
2. Once you have both pendrives attached and your system running, re-partition the old pendrive in *similar manner* to how the second one is partition - that is to say, make the `/boot` partition on the old one have the same number and type as on the new one (refer to the outputs of `fdisk -l`). Don't forget to make it bootable.
3. Clear (keeping a backup somewhere) the contents of `/boot/` on the old pendrv and copy all the files from the new one.
4. **Unmount** both pendrives, remembering which is which (i mean `/dev/sd[ab]` etc.)
5. Overwrite the bootsector of your old pendrive with the one from your new:

   **Here, I'm assuming `/dev/sdb` is your OLD pendrive and `/dev/sdc` is the NEW one** - make **sure** to replace those with appropriate device names, otherwise you can even mess up your entire system!

   > dd if=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1 of=/dev/sdb

Once again, the `if=` parameter must point to the new one - the one that works fine now and the `of=` parameter must point to the OLD pendrive (the one to be fixed).

That should be it. The old pendrive should work just as the new one now.

Comment: You are my hero! I didn't run all steps, after reading your solution I copied both boot sectors to files and compared them. They differed! Then I copied one MBR to another as you wrote in step (5). And after that I finally get my system exactly as before. How can I add 1 million points to your account? ;-) But seriously, I guess the solution to my other problem http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18195/how-to-make-grub-work-again-after-drive-reassignment which you already know is to create MBR having only install CD. Could you tell how to do it in the *OTHER* post? This would be solution.

Comment: :) Great. I'm happy with your happiness :)